# SimpleCursorTreeAdapter - How to customize Child layout

Tags: android, layout

I have been playing around with following android app example.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList2.html

I am able to trigger an action when a child is clicked however I cannot seem to figure out
how to:
1. Customize the label of each child.
2. Change how each child looks. (for example I would like each child to display the phone number and then two graphical buttons on the right. Each button would have a custom action tied to it.)

Any code or links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader

Comment: The link to sample code is broken. That code is now at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList2.java

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution might be to  set a [SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.ViewBinder.html) using [setViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.html#setViewBinder(android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.ViewBinder)), much like you would for a SimpleCursorAdapter.

I am not at all sure that this will work, since I have not tried it, but it seems to be similar. I am trying to solve the same problem, so if it does not work, I'll try to post here.

Comment: Right, so what I've learned so far: The SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.ViewBinder was introduced in API-level 5. I am aiming at a level-4 device. :/

Comment: I'm new to Android and what I'm really struggling with is figuring out how to "take over" the creation of the children so that I can assign layout and add elements programatically. I'm able to change the look of each child using only the XML but when it comes to handling events and assigning dynamic attributes I'm pretty much stomped.

Answer (score 1):

You can override "bindChildView" in your SimpleCursorTreeAdapter. That's how I did it:

```
      class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {

        @Override
    protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.bindChildView(view, context, cursor, isLastChild);

        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Alert.COL_DAY));              
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.child_day)).setText(title);           
    }

        public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor,
                int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo,
                int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {

          super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
        }

        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
          int idColumn = groupCursor.getColumnIndex(Pill.COL_ID);
          return Alert.list(db, groupCursor.getInt(idColumn), null, Alert.COL_DAY);
        }

  }
```

Still, you have to provide childFrom and childTo params to adapter when creating it, so it will use them in bindChildView.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look to [CursorTreeAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html) and bindChildView method.