# avoiding selected group collapse when refreshing (using expandablelistview and cursor loaders

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-cursorloader, simplecursortreeadapter

I am pretty much following the example here [SimpleCursorTreeAdapter and CursorLoader for ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader-for-expandablelistview)
But I also have an async task running to update the database. I notice when I have a group expanded it collapses and then expands right before refreshing. I tracked it down and it seems to be in onLoadFinished right where setChildrenCursor is being set. How can I avoid the blinking while the data is being refreshed. I have looked around everywhere but nothing seems to address this particular problem. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same example and met the same problem. After hours of research I found out that blinking effect was caused by updating the table in database.

In order to prevent blinking, in adapter you need to override `notifyDataSetChanged` like this

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    notifyDataSetChanged(false);
}
```